# Matlab how to define coefficients in a matrix to compute the roots of a polynomial

Tags: matlab, matrix, coefficients

I want to solve the coefficients of this equation in matlab in a matrix.
E + 1/2x^3 - 1/4X^5 -1/4 = 0, where E = 1 and 1/16
So far have I got this. But it doesn't work.

```
if E < 1/8
        coeffs = [E + 1/2 - 1/4 1 0 -1/4];
        sols = roots(coeffs);
        sols = sort(sols,'descend');
        Y = sols(1);
        Z = sols(2);
    else E > 1/8;
        coeffs = [E + 1/2 - 1/4 2 1 0 -1/4];
        sols = roots(coeffs);
        sols = sort(sols,'descend');
        Y = sols(3);
        Z = sols(4);
    end
```

(Where Y and Z are limits of an integral I'm computing later on in the code.)

Where am I going wrong with this? I don't know how to get the coeffs=[] line right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you are trying to compute the roots of the following polynomial:
(-1/4)x^5 + (0)x^4 + (E+1/2)x^3 + (0)x^2 + (0)x + (-1/4) = 0
This is important to clarify.
If my assumption is correct, coeffs = [(-1/4) 0 (E+1/2) 0 0 (-1/4)]

Answer (score 0):

**1.-** `coeffs` is a MATLAB command.

You are not using it correctly :

- operator `*` omission;
- mixing `x` and `X` in the polynomial expression not collecting the result of coeffs in a variable
- It's wise **not using** `reserved words` or `command words` as variables despite MATLAB may likely solve ambiguity correctly.
- I also like keeping **small characters** for **scalars** and `1xN` vectors and **capital characters** for **arrays** `N*M (* ..)  N>1 M>1`
- without collecting the output of `coeffs` the only way to use the resulting coefficients would be to use the system variable `ans` that always collects the most recent result.

So

**2.-** Instead of

```
coeffs = [E + 1/2 - 1/4 1 0 -1/4];
```

try

```
e=1/16
syms x
c1=coeffs(e+1/2*x^3-1/4*x^5-1/4,'All')
```

without the `'All'` option `coeffs` chains all non-zero resulting coefficients, and the resulting polynomial may not the the actual input.

**3.-** Your code is now as follows.

```
N=6;  % precision : amount digits + amount decimals

e=1/16;
syms x
c1=coeffs(e+1/2*x^3-1/4*x^5-1/4,'All')
s1 = round(roots(c1),N);
s1 = sort(s1,'descend')
        
if e < 1/8
        Y = s1(1)
        Z = s1(2)
        
    else e > 1/8
        Y = s1(3)
        Z = s1(4)
        
end
```

The result for `e=1/16` is :

```
c1 =
 
[-1/4, 0, 1/2, 0, 0, -3/16]
 
 
s1 =
 
- 0.31028 + 0.613148i
- 0.31028 - 0.613148i
               1.2823
             0.830187
            -1.491928
```

And the result for `e=1` is :

```
c1 =
 
[-1/4, 0, 1/2, 0, 0, 3/4]
 
 
s1 =
 
  0.424835 + 0.930891i
  0.424835 - 0.930891i
- 1.243788 + 0.449783i
- 1.243788 - 0.449783i
              1.637907
 
 
Y =
 
- 1.243788 + 0.449783i
 
 
Z =
 
- 1.243788 - 0.449783i
```

Comment :  `N=6` sets precision total amount of digits including left dot digits and right side dot decimals.

Otherwise no matter how format is set `roots` forces long precision, and there may be no need to drag along 20 decimals all the way.